# Debug WriteLine Performance Issues on Visual Studio 2017 with Rebuild

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

My C# Web Forms and Web Applications require a LOT of System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline output. The applications processes a LOT of data (by a lot I mean a lot more than most people but a lot less than most significant commercial data apps) about 100s of MBytes or less.

I only use Visual Studio 2017 and C# SQL Server Express..and I'd like to continue to use them.  However, upgrading to HPs i7 CPUs (either Spectre X360 or even the fastest CPUs DAMEN i7 OMEN 6 Core i8 CPUs), and doing a reinstall then slows the application testing/debuggin to an absolute crawl... it's not use-able. (Although processing not in Debug (Writeline output) is screaming fast)

So my next question is What IDE can I use to replace VISUAL STUDIO if I can not get this resolved very quickly?  IMPORTANT NOTE:  I have turned off literally every feature in MS VS2017 Tools --> Options that all Posts found have suggested still to no benefit.

Comment: Git rid of it the Debug.Write code and switch to log4net and write your own appender that can write to a memory mapped file.  Limit the appender to 2GB or so (2gb of ram) and have it rollover when capped.  It's only for debugging, so would give you a really fast way to log and view the contents.  In your configuration, turn off that appender when in Release configuration.

Comment: Thank you for that comment @Ryan I discovered the Visual Studio Issue but will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record:  Thanks @Stom for info -- in my case I do want fast test data.. (nothing else)... howevever I found the solution!!

To my surprise and amazement after trying every options in Tools -> Options -> Debug Etc Etc Etc and many others I found the ONE setting that is the most important for Debug Output using Multi Core processors (like more than 2) is :

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run ->  X Maximum Number of Parallel Projects

Set this to the number of actual cores running on your CPU (ie .. likely not 12 as is default).

Whalaa... Debug Output 10000 x Faster.

Comment: I am glad you found your solution. I still stand behind my answer, as it is the fastest way to display console like data - no multi-threading required.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Diagnostics.**Debug**.Writeline method is quick way to output debugging data and should not be used in production or large output scenarios. 
Use the File class to output the data to a file, and write a separate Monitoring program to read and display the file as it changes.